# is there a way to hide a container item while a particular view is rendered?

Tags: authentication, extjs, show-hide

I've tried to make an modern desktop web application with ext js. The main view of the app has 4 child views: menu, header, footer and center views.I wanna hide them when this login view bellow is displayed.but I don't know which trick to use.

```js
Ext.define('App.view.auth.Login', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'authlogin',

    controller: 'authlogin',

    cls: 'auth-login',

    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'center',
        pack: 'center'
    },

    items: [{
        cls: 'auth-header',
        html:
            '<span class="logo x-fa fa-circle-o-notch"></span>'+
            '<div class="title">Coworkee</div>'+
            '<div class="caption">Employee directory</div>'
    }, {
        xtype: 'formpanel',
        reference: 'form',
        layout: 'vbox',
        ui: 'auth',

        items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name: 'username',
            placeholder: 'Username',
            required: true
        }, {
            xtype: 'passwordfield',
            name: 'password',
            placeholder: 'Password',
            required: true
        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'LOG IN',
            iconAlign: 'right',
            iconCls: 'x-fa fa-angle-right',
            handler: 'onLoginTap',
            ui: 'action'
        }]
    }, {
        cls: 'auth-footer',
        html:
            '<div>Ext JS example</div>'+
            '<a href="http://www.sencha.com" target="_blank">'+
                '<span class="logo ext ext-sencha"></span>'+
                '<span class="label">Sencha</span>'+
            '</a>'
    }]
});
```

Comment: Instead of hiding everything you might not need you might be interested in the routing system.(https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/guides/application_architecture/router.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Routing is the best strategy but if you don't want to use that, you can create a function which returns boolean value based on user's login status. Then you can bind that login status with any view's hidden property which will do the trick.

Comment: You can follow the fiddle -
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/341b
There is MainView.js file, which contains 2 hidden items and are visible once you click on login button, hope that helps !